# Why is PIL.ImageGrab.grab giving black screen

Tags: windows, screenshot

Why is `PIL.ImageGrab.grab()` giving black screen for a specific app? Are there any ways software could have blocked taking screenshots in Windows OS (it's an .exe application) and if yes, is there a way to disable it? I checked and even Win+PrtScr gave the black screen on the same screens of this software, so it seems like this has nothing to do with PIL but with some sort of blanket ban overtaking screenshots. I know I can take photos of the screen with camera but I want to automate my boring tasks so I'm looking for a programmable solution.